# Regex for Australian phone numbers WITH toll-free numbers

Tags: regex

There are a number of questions about regex for Australian phone numbers. They cover things like:

```
0411 123 123
0411123123
+61 411 123 123
+61411123123
(03) 9999 9999
(02)99999999
07 9999 9999
0899999999
```

The working JS regex for this is below and here https://regex101.com/r/bRbrVZ/1

```
/^(?:\+?(61))? ?(?:\((?=.*\)))?(0?[2-57-8])\)? ?(\d\d(?:[- ](?=\d{3})|(?!\d\d[- ]?\d[- ]))\d\d[- ]?\d[- ]?\d{3})$/
```

BUT, I can't work out where to add to this our free call and local call numbers:

```
13 11 22
131122

1300 111 222
1300111222

1800 111 222
1800111222

And these numbers can't be prefixed with +61
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hint: Use an alternation.

Comment: Please indicate which initial characters of each example string are required. Are we to assume that all phone numbers begin `"0411"`, `"+61"`, `"(03)"`, `"(02)"`, `"07"` or `"08"`, or that, say, the pattern of numbers beginning `"+61"` might instead begin `"+62"` or `"+21"`?

Comment: Yes, when a country code is used, it will always be +61. But not on the 13 or 18 numbers.

Answer (score 0):

I have come up with this. I feel it's a bit crude, but it works

```
^(?:\+?(61))? ?(?:\((?=.*\)))?(0?[2-57-8])\)? ?(\d\d(?:[- ](?=\d{3})|(?!\d\d[- ]?\d[- ]))\d\d[- ]?\d[- ]?\d{3})|(13\s?(\d?\s?\d{3}?|\s?\d{2}\s?\d{2})|1[38]00\s?(\d{2}\s?\d{2}\s?\d{2}|\d{3}\s?\d{3}))$
```

https://regex101.com/r/ay4R67/2/